# Instantiating Object in a method from Type passed as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I'm trying to pass a Type to a method and have it instantiate an Object of said Type. I have a lot of repeated code which resembles:

```
foreach (Link link in links)
{
    Object obj = new Object(link);
    list.Add("Description" + obj.prop.ToString());
}
```

With numerous different classes/objects.

I envision:

```
private void populateList(List<Link> links, Type type, List<val> list, string desc)
{
    foreach (Link link in links)
    {
        //Instantiate Object from type parameter here?
        list.Add(desc + obj.prop.ToString());
    }
}
```

I attempted to use Generics and Reflection to solve the problem:

```
Type[] typeArgs = {typeof(Link)};
Type constructed = type.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```

But I wasn't too sure where to go next as I'm not able to use either o or constructed to do what I need.

I'm a complete beginner with Reflection and Generics so I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is possible. I'd appreciate any advice on where to go next or any potential solutions.

Comment: which is the generic type ? Link ?

Comment: @Dave Zych Text pulled from text boxes/drop down lists. Once I've looped through all the Objects I use the resulting list of props to populate a report.

Comment: @tonedlemming meaning each `Type` has a different list of props?

Comment: @Fabio Salvalai I'm not entirely sure, my understanding is that I would have an Object in the method of the type I pass through to the method in the parameter. I would then loop through the list of links (which are all the same type of object) and pass them through to the Objects constructor.

Comment: @Dave Zych Yes, some common props are found in each such as a date field but that's where the similarities end. Each Type is an input form, and the props are the fields in the form, text fields/dropdown boxes etc.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection works for this purpose

```
public static T GenerateNewInstance<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    Type type = typeof (T);
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return instance as T;
}
```

I think what you're having trouble with is accessing the object properties (prop?) The compiler doesn't know what specific object type you're working with as it's being cast as an object.

You could make that work runtime using something like:

```
obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(obj);
```

But ultimately it's a matter of casting the object to a specific class:

```
class obj = (class)obj;
list.Add(obj.property.ToString());
```

Edit: I might not understand your question correctly. 
It also seems like you want to pass different type's. Does the original classes have identical properties or do you just want to add all the properties from a given object into the list?

If they have identical properties, consider creating an interface with those properties and make your classes implement it, that way you can create a new instance of the objects and cast it as the interface and thereby get the properties they share.

Comment: No, sorry, the original classes all have different properties. I should have mentioned in the question that each Type is basically an input form and the prop fields are input fields in the form, such as text fields, drop down boxes etc.